# Difficulty Retrieving Highest Quality Images from Wikimedia Using get_main_image Function

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, wikipedia

I'm facing an issue with the `get_main_image` function in my Python script designed to scrape images from Wikimedia. The problem lies in the function's behaviour of downloading smaller images instead of the highest quality versions available.

Here's a brief overview of the issue:

- The get_main_image function is responsible for retrieving and saving images from Wikimedia.
- However, it seems to be consistently downloading smaller or lower-quality versions of the images.
- My goal is to modify the function to ensure it retrieves the largest and clearest version of the image available on Wikimedia.

I suspect that there might be a flaw in how the function identifies and fetches the image URLs or perhaps in the selection process for the image quality.

Below is a simplified version of the `get_main_image` function:

```
import requests

def get_main_image(wiki_link,article, save_dir, IMAGE_NUM):
  headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
  }
  image_url = wiki_link + article.replace(" ", "_")
  image_name = str(IMAGE_NUM + 1)
  response = requests.get(image_url)
  soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')

  try:
    main_image_url = soup.find('img', alt=article).get('srcset')
    main_image_response = requests.get(url = main_image_url,headers= headers, stream=True)
  except Exception as e:
    #print(e)
    try:
      main_image_url = soup.find('img', alt=article).get('src')
      main_image_response = requests.get(url = main_image_url,headers= headers, stream=True)
    except:
      return image_url, None

  #print(article.replace(" ", "_")[5:])
  #print(article[-4:])
  if article[-4:] == ".svg":
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(main_image_response.content))
    image_name = image_name + ".png"
    save_path = save_dir + "//" + image_name 
    #print(article.replace(" ", "_")[5:] + ".png")
    image.save(save_path)
  elif article[-5:] == ".djvu":
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(main_image_response.content))
    image_name = image_name + ".jpg"
    save_path = save_dir + "//" + image_name
    #print(article.replace(" ", "_")[5:] + ".jpg")
    image.save(save_path)
  else:
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(main_image_response.content))
    image_name = image_name + article[-4:]
    save_path = save_dir + "//" + image_name
    #print(article.replace(" ", "_")[5:])
    #print("I haven't caused an error yet")
    try:
      image.save(save_path)
    except Exception as e:
      image_name = None
  return image_url, image_name
```

EDIT:
For example, this image (i.e. the main image on the URL) is downloaded as 1.09 mb when it is 4.33 mb. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_Potential_Nuclear_Strike_Targets_(c._2015),_FEMA.png

Comment: Can you share a wikipedia URL and what image from this URL you want to get, for example?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I've edited my question and added an example URL and Image. Thank you for you time

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can use [Wikimedia Commons API](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:API) to get URL of full sized image, for example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://magnus-toolserver.toolforge.org/commonsapi.php"
image_name = "Map_of_Potential_Nuclear_Strike_Targets_(c._2015),_FEMA.png"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, params={"image": image_name}).content, "xml")
# print(soup.prettify())

print(soup.urls.file.text)
```

Prints:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Map_of_Potential_Nuclear_Strike_Targets_%28c._2015%29%2C_FEMA.png
```

Comment: My code is still downloading 10mb photos as  1mb picture